# response() em XML com Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, xml, api

Tenho estudado sobre o desenvolvimento de APIs com Laravel, uma dúvida rápida, é possivel retornar um XML em vez de um json?

em vez de fazer:

```
return response()->json($json);
```

fazer algo como:

```
return response()->xml($xml);
```

procurei por XML na documentação e não achei...

Comment: não é a resposta da sua pergunta mas... porque  você quer retornar XML? JSON é muito melhor em vários aspectos, principalmente porque é muito mais fácil de serializar ou deserializar...

Comment: a resposta é a sua pergunta kkkk, o XML já é mais complicado e para completar o meu é assinado, se eu serializar ou deserializar, a assinatura vai se tornar inválida. Preciso passar ele sem fazer nenhuma modificação.

Comment: O que estou fazendo no momento é pegar esse XML via FTP, mas para uma API isso é complicado pois tenho que criar uma conta de FTP para cada aplicação que consumir a API...

Comment: esse XML vem de algum diretório na maquina que está rodando ou ele está em memória?

Comment: ele fica em memória logo após é salvo na máquina, eu gostaria de enviar antes de ser salvo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja essa extensão, funciona bem: https://github.com/jailtonsc/laravel-response-xml

Laravel não trabalha com xml nativamente

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Parece ser o que preciso, vou fazer alguns testes

Comment: Hmmm, boa, acredito que a resposta do Flavio seja a mais correta, mas vou manter a minha pois é uma maneira diferente de fazer o que vc queria.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe nada relacionado a XML em especifico, mas encontrei [esse documento](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-responses) que fala de download de arquivo. Mas para isso você precisa baixa-lo na maquina antes de envia-lo.

```
return response()->download($pathToFile); 

return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);

return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

`$pathToFile` é o diretório onde  você salvou seu XML. Você pode usar 3 tipos de parâmetros.

- O primeiro você passa apenas o caminho do arquivo.
- O segundo você caminho, nome e os headers
- O terceiro você passa o caminho e especifica se vai ou não deleta-lo após o download.

Comment: Mesmo a solução anterior ser o que preciso, sua resposta me deu uma ideia de solução dentro do laravel, vou fazer testes

Comment: @JeffersonCarlosBD boa ;)

Comment: @JeffersonCarlosBD não esquece de marcar a pergunta dele como a correta ok ?